# How can I get a list of process IDs on the system under Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-mint

I need to list the process IDs on the Linux command line. Can I use the `ls` command in the `/proc` directory?

The problem is that it lists some process IDs with file names. Can I remove those names using some `ls` command option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just list your current processes, use:

```
ps
```

To see every process on the system:

```
ps -ef
```

To show only the PID:

```
ps -e -o pid
```

Here, `-e` selects all processes and `-o pid` outputs only the PIDs.

Read `man ps` for more info.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just for curiosity I was thinking if there is any way to manipulate ls command and /proc directory to list process ids?

Comment: Probably `ls | grep -o '[0-9]*'`, but that's not really recommended.

Comment: @techfun: To get the list of process IDs from **/proc** using `ls`, run `ls -d /proc/*[[:digit:]]* | cut -d\/ -f3`.