# How can I get files with numeric names using ls command?

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-mint

In linux commandline, how can I list down only numeric(only names with 0 to 9) file names in the current directory?

This is a follow-on question to [How can I get the list of process ids on the system in linux command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/715995/), where I've run `ls` on `/proc/`.  I'm now trying to exclude everything except the process ID directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `ls` piped to  `grep -E` (extended grep with additional regexp capabilities) to search for all filenames with only numeric characters:

```
ls | grep -E '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: why downvote please?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I strongly suspect (no pun intended) that it's because [you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Even more so in a case like this, where perfectly valid alternatives exist (see for example [mpy's answer](http://superuser.com/a/716057/53590)).

Comment: hmm... despite `ls` specifically requested by OP. Thanks for link.

Comment: You're right, the question title says `ls`, but the question itself is much broader and only asks how to list files with numeric file names from the command line. `ls` is one way to do that (and it's one way to list files), but far from the only one. Try e.g. `echo *` some time.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Answer (score 7):

Despite of your question title, I want to present you a solution with `find`. It has a regex option (`-regex`), so `[0-9]*` will match file names consisting solely out of digits.

To find only files (`-type f`) recursively below the current directory (`.`)  use

```
find . -type f -regex ".*/[0-9]*"
```

The `.*/` in the regex is necessary, because regex "*is a match on the whole path, not a search.*" (`man find`). So if you want to find only files in the current dir, use `\./` instead:

```
find . -type f -regex "\./[0-9]*"
```

However, this is not very optimal, as find searches recursively also in this case and only filters out the desired results afterwards.

Comment: I think this is a really excellent answer; thank you for the recursive / mon-recursive versions!

Answer (score 6):

If you're wanting to use `ls`, you could use:

```
ls *[[:digit:]]*
```

The `*` splat operator will match any `[[:digit:]]`.  You could also use:

```
ls *[0-9]*
```

Which also matches file or directory with a digit 0-9.

If you have subdirectories that match the glob pattern, you can use the `-d` switch to make ls not recurse into them.

Comment: Note: this will list files _starting_ with a digit. Add another "*" at the end to match also files with digits inbetween.

Comment: These patterns will only match files which *end* with a numeric character.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for reply. I have some confusion with ls 
*[0-9] I am getting list of files inside sub directories and files with numeric. And for sub directories it is again listing all directories.

Comment: @techfun Add the `-d` switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ls +([0-9])` to match only files with numeric names.

Comment: so what makes it different from tijko's answer?

Comment: tijko's answer does not work correctly. It would match a2g.test but my answer just match numbers.

Comment: As @techfun mentioned "only numeric(only names with 0 to 9) file names"  tijko's answer doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the reminder from @MOHRE, but I had to remember to set extended pattern matching
`shopt -s extglob`

The shopt builtin can set e.g. `shopt -s *someshelloption*` or unset `shopt -u *someshelloption*`.

from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889744/what-is-the-purpose-of-shopt-s-extglob) :
Composite patterns may be formed using  one  or  more  of  the
following sub-patterns:

```
  ?(pattern-list)
         Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
  *(pattern-list)
         Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
  +(pattern-list)
         Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
  @(pattern-list)
         Matches one of the given patterns
  !(pattern-list)
         Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```